# Angular $routeProvider - Adding Route Resolve Programmatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'd like to add Angular `resolve` dynamically after it was defined by the app. Imagine, my app is defined with routes like this:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {templateUrl: "partials/home.html", controller: "PageCtrl"   })
    .when("/services", {templateUrl: "partials/services.html", controller: "PageCtrl"   })
}]);
```

Then later I want to add/edit/override specific route(s) to `resolve` a promise:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/services", {templateUrl: "partials/services.html", controller: "PageCtrl",  ,resolve:{getData: function(myService){return myService.getOffer();}}    })
}]);
```

How do I do this? The key here is adding after it was defined/configured. So this code will run at some point in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is

```
app.run(function ($route) {
  var route = $route.routes['/...'];
  route.resolve = route.resolve || {};
  route.resolve.someResolver = ...;
});
```

Comment: This does nicely work for the page I add resolve to (eg: $route.routes['/services'];)... But when I go to other pages I get Angular Error: [$injector:unpr]

Comment: Since you use the same controller for all routes, I guess you're injecting a resolver there on the route where you didn't define this resolver.

Comment: I added route.controller = "PageCtrl"; inside - but that did not fix. Is this what you refer to?

Comment: Please, post your controller code. I assume that you're injecting a resolver into the controller on the route which doesn't have this resolver.

Comment: I understood. Thank you. I indeed was injecting a undefined resolver into the controller

Comment: Accepted answer. Do you know by any chance how to pass resolver to controller's $scope in a similar way. I want to use this resolver's data in routeChangeSuccess event. Thanks!

Comment: The resolver can save its resolution in any service (or better to be a shallow wrapper for the service). You may also get the control over 'resolve' resolutions in [current.$$route.locals](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#$routeChangeSuccess). Feel free to post a question with your current code if you will still have problems with solving it.

Comment: I posted similar question but for UI-Router instead of ngRoute http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739533/angular-run-block-use-ui-router-stateprovider-to-resolve-promise It has bounty if you can help