# $stateProvider change template depending on user

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Okay this question is abit long but i feel like ive tried everything so i hope you will help me out if you can :)

So basicly my system has two user types: `Admin` & `Client` these types are bound to a template `tpl/app.html` & `tpl/client/client.html`

Now instead of defining states twice (1 for `Admin` & 1 for `client`)  i wish to make a logic that serves the correct template no matter what

For this purpose i read the [Documentation for $stateProvider](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) and found that i am  able to set the `templateUrl` to a function:

```
  templateProvider: function ($sessionStorage) {
                        return template;
                    },
```

Using this syntax i was able to do something like this:

```
templateProvider: function ($sessionStorage) {
    var templateLocation = $sessionStorage.user.type == 'Admin' ? 'tpl/app.html' : 'tpl/client/client.html';
   return '<div ng-include="'+templateLocation+'"> </div>' 
},
```

Now there are two things wrong with this

1. First of all for some reason this doesnt work. it does set the url to the correct template however it is never injected into the html instead i get this:

   ```
   <div>   <!-- ngInclude: tpl/client/client.html -->    </div>
   ```
2. The idea is fine however making the above code for each abstract state seems tedious and very redundant.

Because of #2 i decided to create a decorator. however the `decorator` has a problem aswell. It simply cannot use the service `$sessionStorage` where my user data is in meaning that i am unable to know which user is attempting to reach the content.

So now i feel like im out of options.

I hope that some of you might be able to help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't necessary to write WET anonymous function for each abstract state.

```
function userTemplateProvider($sessionStorage, $templateRequest) {
    var templateLocation = $sessionStorage.user.type == 'Admin' ? 'tpl/app.html' : 'tpl/client/client.html';
   return $templateRequest(templateLocation); 
},

...
templateProvider: userTemplateProvider
```

Angular `decorator` won't help with UI Router states because it would affect `$state` instance and not `$stateProvider` provider. `$stateProvider.state` method [can be patched directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33813535/3731501) to modify state object, though it is hardly can be considered a justified solution in this case.

Comment: The above code works but i can figure out if your saying its recommended or not?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen The supplied code is the recommended DRY solution. It can be made even DRYer by patching $stateProvider.state, but I wouldn't recommend that.